# Split a field and add these fields to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has a field that allows up to 120 chars. I want to split the field into three fields. If the field contains more than 40 chars and less than 80 then split the field into two. The split point should be the first space char, before the 40th character and add the two new fields to another table. and if the field is 120 char then split them in three.

Will appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could do something along the lines of:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(MyCol,1,40), 
  NULLIF(SUBSTRING(MyCol,41,40), ''),
  NULLIF(SUBSTRING(MyCol,81,40), ''),
```

To have your 1 column broken down correctly for your `INSERT` statement.

The `NullIf` function will set whatever column needs to be `NULL` correctly if the `SubString()` function returns an empty string for that value.

Comment: The logic is good. But the questioner wants a split at a last space character within the 40 chars of split interest. ( that would either break the usecase and introduce a 4th field if there are 4 satisfying spaces in those 120 characters )